# C - Passing a local variable in a function without initializing

Tags: c, variables, local, initializing

so I'm really new at this, and I was wondering how I would go about passing a local variable in a function (in terms of the initialization). For example, I have one function (move) that declares and initializes two variables (t_row and t_column) to be used in a for loop, and within that loop, I have another functions (swap), that is called if certain conditions are met. How do I go about using those variables in the swap function. I know I need to declare them, but their initialization in the swap function depends on what iteration of the for loop swap was called. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
bool move(int tile)
{
    for (int t_row = 0; t_row < d; t_row++)
    {
        for (int t_column = 0; t_column < d; t_column++)
        {
            if (tile == board[t_row][t_column])
            {
                if (0 < t_row && board[t_row - 1][t_column] == 0)
                {
                    swap(t_row - 1, t_column);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        return false;
}

void swap(int row_new, int column_new)
{
    int t_row;
    int t_column;        
    int hold = board[t_row][t_column];
    board[t_row][t_column] = 0;
    board[row_new][column_new] = hold;
}
```

Comment: `Calling a local variable`...hmmm.

Comment: If you pass them in, just use them.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can see to do this would be to pass in the values of the old row and column.

```
void swap(int row_new, int col_new, int row_old, int col_old) {
    int hold = board[row_old][col_old];
    board[row_old][column_old] = 0;
    board[row_new][column_new] = hold;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was considering doing that, but it just seemed redundant since the row_old and row_new would be the same variable every time I called it, and I actually end up calling it a few times, but that works. Thank you!